# sqlite, get field from updated

Tags: bash, sqlite

I have a an sqlite database with the table test. Several processes are accessing this database from bash. The table has the following fields:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id NUMERIC,
start JULIAN,
finish JULIAN)
```

I obtain an unique id by:

```
id=$(sqlite test.db <<EOF
BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE start IS NULL ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
COMMIT;
EOF
)
```

My question is, how can update the field start with:

```
UPDATE mytable set start=julianday('now') where id="SELECTED ID FROM ABOVE";
```

In the same statement?

Comment: Most ORM's will grab the id value before applying it, so that the id is known for application use.  If you do a direct select within your update as above, you won't know the ID of the entry that you just created without doing a table scan.  Are you certain you shouldn't just use application code to get the id, then create it with that id passed as an argument, unless you have an unusual set of application rules that prevent that.

Comment: So I would do the following steps: 1) lock the database, 2) query for an id and assign it to a variable in my application, 3) update that id,4) unlock the data base? Thanks for your comments

Comment: I guess you if you don't actually need that ID afterwards, you should be able to run the following: UPDATE mytable set start=julianday('now') where id in (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE start IS NULL ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1); but I don't know what you actual end game is in this.

Comment: The problem is that I do need the id afterwards.

Comment: OK, then you should do it in the application code - run a begin trans, then get your ID through the application DB linkage, then run the update directly with that ID.  I'll write up how I'd do it in perl right after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments that you supplied above, my solution would look something like follows (in perl with a raw DBI connection, also i didn't do a lot of error checking or anything either, something that you should probably do):

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(...);
$dbh->do("BEGIN EXCLUSIVE");
my $stm = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE start IS NULL ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1");
$stm->execute();
my $row = $stm->fetchrow_hashref();
my $id = undef;
if ( $row ) {
    $id = $row->{ID};
    my $ustm = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE mytable set start=julianday('now') where id=?");
    $ustm->execute($id);
}
$dbh->do("COMMIT");
# Still have the id at this point.
```